# Mirror Image and shield combo

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, shield

On the topic of mirror image and shield combo, lets say a creature successfully attacks the real one and then the defender decides to use shield as a reaction, which comes first and which has priority?

Comment: Anyway, welcome to the stack! Take the [tour] and review the articles at the [help] to get acquainted with how we do things here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### *Mirror image* is resolved before *shield* can be cast.

*Shield* requires that you be hit by an attack, having a casting time of 1 Reaction:

> which you take *when you are hit* by an attack or targeted by the magic missile spell

*Mirror image* is triggered *before* you are hit with an attack:

> Each time a creature *targets you* with an attack during the spell's duration, roll a d20 to determine whether the attack instead targets one of your duplicates.

So *mirror image* is always resolved before the trigger for *shield* can even happen.

Comment: Might be worth going into further explanation for if the caster is targeted by magic missile instead since the wording for the shield spell differs.

Comment: @Clarus_Nox OP seems to ask specifically about attacks. But the ruling is that *magic missile* ignores *mirror image* entirely.